# JAXB define java class for a xml file with attributes in nested elements

Tags: jaxb

I want to define a java class and then use JAXB to marshalling its instances to a xml file.

The output I want looks like:

```
<paths>
<path action="R" kind="file" copyfrom-path="file1" copyto-path="file2">file2</path>
<path action="M" kind="file">file3</path>
</paths>
```

I defined a java class as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "paths")
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class changed_paths
{

    private List<String> path;

    public changed_paths()
    {
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getPath()
    {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(List<String> path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void addPath(String p)
    {
        path.add(p);
    }

}
```

Using the above java class, I can generate output xml file without the attributes of `<path></path>` elements. Like below:

```
<paths>
    <path>file2</path>
    <path>file3</path>
</paths>
```

I tried to define the attributes in changed_paths class like below :

```
@XmlAttribute 
private String kind;

public void setKind(String kind){
     this.kind = kind;
}

public String getKind(){
     return this.kind;
}
```

But this will output a xml file with attributes "kind" in tag `<paths></paths>` but not in its nested `<path></path>` tags.

The other problem is that when the attribute name contains "-" (e.g. copyfrom-path), java won't allow me to define such variables with "-" in its name.

Can someone please tell me how to define:
1. attributes in `<path></path>`?
2. attributes with "-" in their names?
Can someone please give me some help?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I find the answers. To create attributes for `<path></path>`, I defined class path for this tag. And defined another class paths for `<paths></paths>` .
To create attributes with "-" in their names, I use annotation `@XmlAttribute(name = "copyfrom-path")`

```
    @XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class path
{
    @XmlAttribute
    private String kind;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String action;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "copyfrom-path")
    private String copyfrom;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "copyfrom-rev")
    private String copyto;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    public void setKind(String kind)
    {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getKind()
    {
        return this.kind;
    }

    public void setAction(String action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String getAction()
    {
        return this.action;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setCopyfrom(String p)
    {
        this.copyfrom = p;
    }

    public String getCopyfrom()
    {
        return this.copyfrom;
    }

    public void setCopyto(String p)
    {
        this.copyto = p;
    }

    public String getCopyto()
    {
        return this.copyto;
    }

}


@XmlRootElement(name = "paths")
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class paths
{

    private List<path> paths;

    public paths()
    {
        paths = new ArrayList<path>();
    }

    public List<path> getPaths()
    {
        return paths;
    }

    public void setPaths(List<path> paths)
    {
        this.paths = paths;
    }

    public void addPath(path p)
    {
        paths.add(p);
    }

}
```